# Eigenvalue problem for $−\psi''(x) − (ix)^ N \psi(x) = E\psi(x)$ in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics

To find the eigenvalue $E$ in the complex plane of $x$ for one dimensional Schrodinger equation
$$
−\psi''(x) − (ix)^ N \psi(x) = E\psi(x).
$$
where $N$ can be any **real** number, the boundary condition  $\psi(x) \to 0$ as $|x| → ∞$ causes a great difficulty for numerical method, because there are infinite number of contour paths which go from zero to complex infinity.

Bender et al on their [**paper**](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9712001) only considered the contour paths (e.g. the black path on the following figure) which are **entirely** confined in two Stokes wedges symmetric with respect to the imaginary axis. Based on my understanding on what they say, each asymptotic series expansion for $ψ(x)$ is only valid within certain sector or wedge, therefore for any path which is outside of these two wedges, the corresponding asymptotic series is no longer asymptotic to the value of the function $ψ(x)$ . However, there exists a new, unique and valid asymptotic series for $ψ(x)$ outside the wedge. Yet, this new asymptotic series, say $f(x)$, does not satisfy the boundary condition  $f(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$ .

[image]

**My question**:
I don't really understand why the contour path has to be entirely inside the Stokes sector. How about the red and yellow path shown on the figure above?
They are partly inside the Stokes wedges. The red path starts from the complex infinity which lies inside the right Stokes wedge and then approaches the origin zero from the left Stokes wedge, so that only the middle part of the red path lies outside the two Stokes sectors. The yellow path starts from the complex infinity which lies inside the right Stokes wedge and then approaches the origin zero inside the right Stokes wedge again.
Why do these red and yellow paths have to be excluded please? If we integrate along anyone of these two paths, does it yield finite eigenvalue and exponentially decayed eigenfunction or not? Why?

Comment: I was going to link you to the Bender paper when I saw the title on the main page since it's a pretty neat treatment, but alas! You already had access to it.

Comment: on page 2 they say that they are not requiring $\psi(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$ for every direction but only in certain sectors of the complex plane (those wedges)

Comment: Bender papers and his [textbook](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387989310) did not give me a very clear explanation why all contour paths have to be restricted "in" these sectors. Here, the word "in" is ambiguous. Does "in" mean "completely in" or "partially in"? This is my original question.

Comment: So I think "in" means "eventually in." In the last paragraph on page 2, Bender says that the differential equation can be integrated on *any* path as long as that path is eventually within the two wedges.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Do you know any simple explanation why Bender said this on his paper? If you read his [textbook](http://www.amazon.com/Advanced-Mathematical-Methods-Scientists-Engineers/dp/0387989315#reader_0387989315) on the page 135, he clearly listed some path as "bad path" even if the "bad path" eventually connected the two desired points. Also, in the section 3.7 on his textbook, when he extended the asymptotic relations in the complex plane, he had to exclude all the paths which rotated around the irregular singular point.

Comment: My guess is that those systems are fairly badly behaved. The one in the paper is pretty tame, all things considered. Asymptotics are often done on a case-by-case basis because there isn't really an overarching program that works in general.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What is the meaning of "tame"? In what criteria we call them "tame"? Another important question is that suppose that the yellow and red path are OK, then if we integrate along anyone of the two paths, does it give the same eigenvalue and eigenfunction as we obtain for those paths inside the wedge? Any justification?

Comment: By tame I mean that there aren't too many pathologies going on. You don't have singularities and such. I would hazard to guess that integrating along either the red or yellow paths is okay and will give the same answer, but don't hold me to it.

Comment: I think the point could be that if u leave ur stoke wedge somewhere, u need to impose additional matching condtions with the solutions outside (continuity most likely). this matching condtions translate in additonal physical constraints/boundary condition, which the original system not supports (u just have the $\psi(\pm \infty)$ condtions). Keep in mind that this is just an educated guess,,,

Comment: Nice question! I upvoted it and am waiting for answers

Answer (score 0):

It absolutely does not matter where the normalization contour starts and how it behaves in the beginning. It only matters how it behaves near infinity. The behavior of solution of your equation is
the following: for every Stokes sector, there is a one-dimensional set of solutions which tend to zero on any path "strictly" within this Stokes sector.
"Strictly" means that if the Stokes sector is $\alpha<\arg z<\beta$ then
the argument on the path $\gamma(t):0\leq t<\infty$ should satisfy 
$$\alpha<\liminf_{t\to\infty}\arg \gamma(t)<\limsup_{t\to\infty}\arg\gamma(t)<\beta-\epsilon,$$
for some $\epsilon>0$. What the path does for finite $t$ is irrelevant,
only $\arg\gamma(t)$ as $t\to\infty$.

So the boundary conditions are essentially determined by choosing two
non-adjacent Stokes sectors where solution tends to $0$, the contour is irrelevant and for computation you can choose whatever contour you wish. No other reasonable boundary conditions at $\infty$ can be imposed.

So all three contours in your picture are fine provided that they stay in the green sector far away from the origin.